# How to write an email after non-response from HR

Tags: interviewing, communication, email, follow-up, email-etiquette

Here's the timeline:

22 days ago- My resume got shortlisted for a role. I was sent a technical test.

12 days ago- I was informed I passed the test and that the executive assistant will be setting up an interview with a manager 'soon' (I was given the name of the manager so was expecting a quick response). I was asked to share my availability with them. I did this the next morning.

I haven't heard back from them since. I emailed them last week but haven't got a response. I know the company is hiring for many positions so I can understand it taking a while. But today will be two weeks and no interview has been scheduled.

Should I write to them one last time for a status update? If yes, how do I frame the email?

Edit: I've been corresponding with the official company email. They CC'd both the executive assistant and the manager when they informed me I'd passed the test. Who should I mark on the email?

Comment: Whatever you decide to do, it would be wise in situation like this to start looking for other opportunities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already followed up once.  They won't forget you if they really want to hire you.  If you do follow up again, the way to frame it is to ask for a timeline for the next steps (if you haven't already).  But realize that both the timeline and the next steps can change.

From [AskAManager](https://www.askamanager.org/2015/08/5-things-you-should-never-do-while-waiting-to-hear-back-about-a-job.html) of things you should NOT do:

> 1. Check in aggressively. It can be nerve-wracking to wait to hear back from an employer after an interview. But if you give into those nerves by contacting before you should or too many times, you risk undermining the good impression you hopefully made when you met with the employer. That means that you shouldn’t check in before their timeline for making a decision has elapsed, or email and then email again when you don’t get a response to your first message after a day or two, or call repeatedly and hang up when you get voicemail (which looks pretty stalker-ish on Caller ID).

> The reality is, hiring often takes much, much longer than either side expects it to. But if an employer wants to hire you, they’re not going to forget about you. If you’re the strongest candidate, you don’t need to do anything to keep yourself in the forefront of the hiring manager’s mind; you’re already there. Following up once – after the timeline they give you for hearing something has passed – is fine, but beyond that, all you can do is be patient and wait to hear.

The answer given in the the comments is a good one.  Do NOT call.  If you must follow up (one more time), use email.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a phone number, call them up first thing. If you do not have a direct phone number, try to find a phone number for the hiring department / public facing department and ask them to connect you with the hiring team.

Over and above that, follow up on the email.

Comment: Given that I know they have a volume of applications, I'm worried that calling them up will seem pushy. Am I wrong in thinking this? As this is my first time applying to positions, I'm not entirely sure what's acceptable. Thanks!

Comment: @Rnovice you don't really have anything to lose if they think you're pushy.

Comment: @Kilisi - except a job offer.  Calling can be a sure way to turn them off.  They are busy too, and you're saying that your needs are more important than theirs.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek perhaps, but that seems edge case and unprofessional to me at best.

Answer (score 0):

I would say email them again, and see if they are still hiring that position, someone might have gotten the position and the company hasn't emailed you back due to your position already being filled. I would put both of their emails on it just in case. However if you feel like thats too much, then email the executive assistant first. If he/she doesnt respond, then email the manager.